# Server container can't connect to MySQL container on network

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

#### Introduction

Hi folks,

I am building a website which I want to deploy to AWS, using Docker containers. Currently I am in the development stage of my website.

In my website, I am using a MySQL database container, a container for my GraphQL server and a container for my React frontend.

The problem I am facing is with my server and database.
(Note, currently I am not using Docker Compose, I am still practising, but I do intend to use it, so just know that I do not currently have a `docker-compose.yml` file to show you)

#### Getting you familiar

This is the command I used to create my MySQL database container:

```
docker run --name larecipe-database --env-file ./env/mysql.env --network larecipe-net -p 3307:3306 -d mysql
```

I am creating a MySQL container, with the name of `larecipe-database`. I am providing an env file for all the environment variables, I am hooking it up with a network called `larecipe-net`, I am exposing the port `3307` which maps to port `3306`, and obviously, I am using the `mysql` image from docker hub.

Here is the env file for my database:

```
MYSQL_USER=raj
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_DATABASE=larecipe
```

That's it for my database, now let me introduce the Dockerfile for my server (heads up, I am using typescript, therefore the `npm run watch`):

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm i

COPY . .

RUN npm run watch

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is the .dockerignore file for my server:

```
node_modules
```

Here is the command I used to create the server image, giving it a tag of `larecipe-server`:

```
docker build -t larecipe-server ./server
```

And here is the command that I used to create my server container:

```
docker run --name larecipe-server --env-file ./env/server.env --network larecipe-net -p 4000:4000 -d larecipe-server
```

Here I am using the `larecipe-server` image I created, creating a container of the same name, giving it an env file, hooking it up with the same network I used for my database container, exposing the port 4000, and running it in detached mode.

Here is the env file for the server (it is identical to the database one):

```
MYSQL_USER=raj
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_DATABASE=larecipe
```

#### The problem

The problem is that my server container is not able to connect to my mysql container.

Here is the code the server uses to connect:

```
const { MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE } = process.env;

await createConnection({
    type: "mysql",
    host: "larecipe-database",
    port: 3307,
    username: MYSQL_USER,
    password: MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: MYSQL_DATABASE,
    logging: true,
    synchronize: true,
    entities: [Recipe, Ingredient, Step, Member],
  })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(chalk.greenBright.bold("server connected to database"));
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
      console.log(chalk.redBright.bold("server not connected to database"));
    });
```

Note:

- The `createConnection()` function is coming from `typeorm`, the library I am using to interact with my database

When I run the following command:

```
docker logs larecipe-server
```

I get the following output:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:3307
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at /app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:863:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.createPool (/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:860:16)
    at MysqlDriver.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:288:51)
    at step (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.22.0.2',
  port: 3307,
  fatal: true
}

server not connected to database
```

My understanding is that I should be able to put `larecipe-database` as my host as both containers are on the same network. I am using port `3307` as that is the port I have exposed.

#### My attempts at success:

The first thing I did was go over to MySQL workbench, and I tried to connect from there, but that didn't work either.

The next thing I did was inspect the network itself, using this command:

```
docker network inspect larecipe-net
```

This is the output I received:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "larecipe-net",
        "Id": "2b20e4bb771b32727adc747259bee4c0c51eda05e396060200faef16336ce983",
        "Created": "2021-11-26T04:30:57.92577585Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "ad3ae92c0acbd90ce2c7da786ef02456626e71f3fd087694528f29239bfe932b": {
                "Name": "larecipe-server",
                "EndpointID": "e4a4fff37d3efb34dcc77b6bcfd9279f1357f48a7b0ccb0461b6041132f2d5bf",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d0b02575ced53453f9b9309a355b92d3ac95c31977fdf0e2ba6e498b1e79884d": {
                "Name": "larecipe-database",
                "EndpointID": "f8cb24ab9e3d7df154eace0cf360d559d58f7e094d0d96c6df5087362250229e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Under the `Containers` property on the object inside the array, I realised that both containers have different `IPv4Address`s. I don't know what this implies, as I am no networking expert, but I tried both addresses, with port `3307`, but I still wasn't able to connect.

Thanks in advance for any feedback and solutions.
Let me know if you need any extra info.

Comment: Can you try disabling SSL in Workbench and connect? My approach would be to get the Workbench connection working first.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but how do you disable SSL in workbench? I don't seem to have the option to do that. The only options I have for SSL are 'Require', 'Require and Verify CA', and 'Require and Verify Identity'.

Comment: Connection method should be `Standard(TCP/IP)` and not `Standard(TCP/IP) over SSL`.
Also have you tried using localhost, i.e without defining a network in Docker ?

Comment: My connection method is indeed using ```Standard(TCP/IP)```, but I still can't disable SSL. Plus, the whole point of using Docker is so that I don't have to use localhost and that my services do not have to depend on my local machine, or that's what I think. I can definitely use localhost, but I want to try using a Docker network.

Comment: There is however an option to do ```Standard(TCP/IP) over SSH```. I'll try that. Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: Don't use SSH. Also make it work with localhost first and then try the network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239601/discussion-between-rocketblast2481-and-shrm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incredible! I solved it! I simply had to change my host to `host.docker.internal`! Now I am going to try to put these containers on a network.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should first check for user permission and grant permission which allow from any host to connect to MySQL Container.

Go inside MySQL container with

```
docker exec -it {container_name} /bin/bash
```

Login to MySQL console with root user name and password. eg.

```
mysql -uroot -proot
```

Get host and user

```
SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;
```

There, you can check there is **%** under host column which is binding with your user.
If you don't see that, you can't call from your host (outside) of container like GUI tools eg. Workbench, DBeaver, etc.
You can set your user to that **%** permission which mean allow connection from any host by updating with below query.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='%' WHERE user='{your_username}';
```

You can grant permission like below.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '{username}'@'%';
```

Update changes

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can check by retrieving user, host with above SELECT query to confirm changes.

I think it will helpful to you.